# How do i convert a DTO into Jsonpatch array?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where i need to update only a few fields in a large DTO. I am trying to use patch. right now i am using BeanWrapper and looping through the entire DTO field by field to create the patch payload. Is there a more elegant/efficient way to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) can help you with this (I haven't had a chance to use it personally but, have seen teammates use it with success for big DTOs).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it using BeanWrapper provided in Spring framework